# Grails programmatic transaction handling

Tags: hibernate, grails, transactions, grails-orm

My Grails app has a a service method that updates a list of artists from last.fm's web service.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
void updateLastFmArtists(Range idRange = null) {

    Artist.list().each { Artist artist ->

        // We could be updating a lot of artists here, the process could take up 
        // to an hour and we don't want to wrap all that in a single transaction
        Artist.withTransaction { status ->
            try {
                updateArtistInfo(artist)

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                status.setRollbackOnly()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each individual artist is updated within it's own transaction, which should be rolled back if an `IOException` is thrown. However, I noticed the following behaviour:

If an attempt to update an artist throws an `IOException` - causing the transaction to be rolled back - then the update of the next artist always fails due to the following error

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: org.example.Artist.topTracks, no session or
>   session was closed

If I change the code above so that each artist is updated within it's own session, this seems to fix the problem,

```
   Artist.withNewSession { session ->
       Artist.withTransaction { status ->
            try {
                updateArtistInfo(artist)

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                status.setRollbackOnly()
            }
        }
   }
```

But I don't understand why I need to do this, i.e. why is that rolling back a transaction seems to close the session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal that rollback makes the session unusable, as it's an unrecoverable error like all Hibernate exceptions. See for example the javadoc of class `ObjectNotFoundException`:

```
/*
 * ...
 *
 * Like all Hibernate exceptions, this exception is considered 
 * unrecoverable.
 *
 */
```

The reason is that the session is a state synchronizer component between the database and objects in memory. The way to treat a rollback in the database would be to rolllback the changes in the objects in memory.

Because this functionality would be hard to implement and of limited use, the decision was taken to make these type of exceptions unrecoverable.

You can try to catch it and continue to use the session but there is no guarantee that the session will be in a consistent state.

**EDIT:**

Here is further references other than the Javadoc, found in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html):

> An exception thrown by Hibernate means you have to rollback your
>   database transaction and close the Session immediately (this is
>   discussed in more detail later in the chapter). If your Session is
>   bound to the application, you have to stop the application. Rolling
>   back the database transaction does not put your business objects back
>   into the state they were at the start of the transaction. This means
>   that the database state and the business objects will be out of sync.
>   Usually this is not a problem, because exceptions are not recoverable
>   and you will have to start over after rollback anyway.

and also:

> If the Session throws an exception, including any SQLException,
>   immediately rollback the database transaction, call Session.close()
>   and discard the Session instance. Certain methods of Session will not
>   leave the session in a consistent state. No exception thrown by
>   Hibernate can be treated as recoverable. Ensure that the Session will
>   be closed by calling close() in a finally block.

Comment: +1 But in this particular case it's not an unhadled exception, it's an exception that I'm catching within the scope of an individual transaction. I find it surprising that this should invalidate the entire session

Comment: I added some more references to this, the advice based on the docs is to start over again with a new session, as  certain methods of Session will not leave the session in a consistent state in case of rollback

Comment: thanks for your help, however, your quotes above talk about exceptions thrown by Hibernate or Hibernate exceptions, but my case does not involve either of these. I guess it's my call to `status.setRollbackOnly()` which invalidates the session rather than the thrown exception

Comment: the problem is that manually invalidating the transaction gives the same result as a thrown Hibernate exception, this quote is key: 'database state and the business objects will be out of sync... and you will have to start over after rollback anyway'. This means that either via an exception thrown or via setRollbackOnly, the session was just not designed to recover from rollbacks, independently of the cause of the rollback